# disabled select tag with selecting option from another select tag with angularjs and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have two select element and I want to disable one select tag by selecting a particular option from another select.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select name="" ng-model="round.evaluation.availability"  required ng-change="update()">

  <option value="">Select Availability </option>
  <option ng-repeat="list in availabilityList" value="{{list.dbValue}}">{{list.displayValue}}</option>
</select>


<select name="" id="" ng-model="round.evaluation.attitude" ng-disabled="isDisabled" required>

  <option value="">Select Attitude</option>
  <option ng-repeat="list in attitudeList" value="{{list.dbValue}}">{{list.displayValue}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is JS:

```
$scope.availabilityList = [{displayValue:"On Time",dbValue:"on_time"},
                           {displayValue:"Late",dbValue:"late"},
                           {displayValue:"No Show",dbValue:"no_show"}]


$scope.attitudeList = [{displayValue:"Bad",dbValue:"bad"},
                       {displayValue:"Normal",dbValue:"normal"},
                       {displayValue:"Great",dbValue:"great"}]
```

Comment: which select disables the other, or what option disables the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-disabled="round.evaluation.availability == 'no_show'"
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9951/

Comment: You can approve my answer, it will help me a lot, thanks :)